How can a Helm function access a value without knowning the name?
I'm working on a Helm chart and trying to create a general-purpose templating function. The goal is to pass in any parameter (e.g., .Values.name) and have the function template it without knowing the specifics of the parameter.
The function should accept a parameter like .Values.name.
It should evaluate the parameter using tpl if a certain condition (e.g., .Values.enableTpl) is met.
The function should handle various types, such as strings and lists.
{{- define "function" -}}
  {{- $value := . -}} <-- this should pick up the parameter
  {{- if .Values.enableTpl }}
    {{ tpl $value $ }}
  {{- else }}
    {{ $value }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}

# Usage in template
{{ include "function" .Values.name }} <-- function should not know about this parameter

When trying this, I’m encountering the error: "can't evaluate field Values in type string" when trying to check the enableTpl condition.
Removing the enableTpl check also fails, as the . is not the actual parameter ".Values.name"

Note that this is an abstraction of my problem, so please don't question the reasoning for not just doing it without the include :)

"...please don't question the reasoning ...": honestly, reasoning matters - because there might be a better or easier way to do whatever you need to do. I've seen way too many people here on SO complicating things too much due to lack of experience, not being familiar with the tools/technologies, etc. So it is always helpful to understand the scenario and the motivation behind what people are trying to do.

This also sounds to me like an XY problem.  Why would you want to globally disable a built-in function like this?  Does anything bad happen if you unnecessarily call tpl?  Can you move the required templating into template code (files in the templates/* directory), so that you don't need to call tpl at all (are you trying to pass code and not configuration via Helm values)?

The Helm syntax for this is a little tricky.  A Go-template function only takes a single parameter, and within that function both the default value of . and $ are set to that parameter.
This means that, if you need both some value and also the top-level Helm object, you need to pack them together into a single object.  I've historically done this via putting both objects into a list
{{ include "function" (list .Values.name .) }}

and then in the function unpacking them.
{{- define "function" -}}
{{- $value := index . 0 -}}
{{- $top := index . 1 -}}
{{- if $top.Values.enableTpl -}}
{{- tpl $value $top -}}
...

Note that we've passed the top-level Helm object explicitly as a parameter; unpacked it to $top within the function; and then anywhere we need a field off of that, qualified it as access to $top.
You can also pass the two "parameters" as a map dict "value" .Values.name "top" ..  If you do then you don't need to unpack them in the function, and can directly refer to e.g. .top.Values.enableTpl or tpl .value .top.  This pushes some complexity from the function to the caller.  Neither pattern is that common but I've seen both.

For me this results in a can't evaluate field Values in type []interface {}

That probably means you referenced .Values.something inside the function, where you need $top.Values.something.  The . at the front of the expression is a variable and it has a different value inside the function.

You are correct. I missed one of the .s. This was likely my issue from the start, as I had tried it with list before
